# Can I pair both a logitec Crayon and a Brydge keyboard with my ipad (6th gen) at the same time?

Tags: ios, keyboard, bluetooth, stylus

Given my ability to lose pens, I want to use as cheap a stylus as possible with my ipad. Most of the alternatives use bluetooth, as does the Brydge keyboard.  Can I use both at once, or do I have find a non-blue-tooth stylus.

Multiple matching doesn't aways work:  My Subaru will talk to my phone or my wife's phone at any given time.  I have to manually switch from one phone to the other from the Subaru audio centre.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect multiple bluetooth devices at one time to any device that supports bluetooth.

There's nothing special about the iPad bluetooth setup.  I have a few iPads and I connect Apple Pencils and bluetooth speakers and a Brydge keyboard to them at the same time.

To address your edit to your question, you can't use more than one device of the same profile at the same time, i.e. 2 BT speakers or 2 iPhones.  That's just how BT works and isn't unique to Apple products.

The pencil and the keyboard are different device types so you can use them at the same time.

Comment: Well, my subaru won't connect to both my phone and my wife's at the same time.  We have to manually switch over.  But auto bluetooth may be a few versions behind.  Take my upvote.

Comment: That's because both iPhones use the same profile.  This is similar to using bluetooth speaker/headphones at the same time; you can't.  With BT, you can't use two of the same type of devices at the same time.